# Errors with declared array/table variable values in SAP HanaDB SQL

Tags: ado.net, hana

I am trying to add a declared variable to replace a hardcoded list of values in a "where in" clause.
Researching how Hana handles array variables it seems like I can do this by declaring an array and then either using a select directly on it or by unnesting it first into a table but I keep getting errors I can't resolve.

When I try it this way:

```sql
DO
BEGIN

  DECLARE CODES_ARRAY NVARCHAR(100) ARRAY = ARRAY('01','02','03','04');

  SELECT T0."ItemCode"
  FROM OITM T0
    INNER JOIN OITW T1 ON T0."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode"
  WHERE "WhsCode" IN (SELECT "code" FROM :CODES_ARRAY); -- line 9 where error occurs

END;
```

I get this error message `sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near ")": line 9 col 54 (at pos 239)`

I can't figure out what the syntax error resolution is.

So then I tried inserting a declared table variable like this:

```sql
DO
BEGIN

  DECLARE CODES_ARRAY NVARCHAR(100) ARRAY = ARRAY('01','02','03','04');
  DECLARE CODES_TABLE TABLE = UNNEST(:CODES_ARRAY) AS ("code"); -- line 5 where error occurs

  SELECT T0."ItemCode"
  FROM OITM T0
    INNER JOIN OITW T1 ON T0."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode"
  WHERE "WhsCode" IN (SELECT "code" FROM CODES_TABLE); -- I know : is missing here but when adding, the same error from previous block shows up

END;
```

and I get this error message: `identifier must be declared: 1: line 5 col 38 (at pos 123)`

As far as I can tell the array variable is declared as it should be so I don't know how to resolve the error.

I've read the SAP Hana SQL Reference documentation (for array/table variables, unnest function, etc.) over and over and it seems like I've got everything setup correctly but can't figure out these errors. I would like to be able to use both of these approaches at different times if possible (the "array variable to table variable" and the "array variable only" approaches)

I don't know exactly what is going on here, but one thing I notice that the two different error messages referenced in my post (see difference from errors in the first two code blocks) is that each error is occurring either immediately before the use of the variable with the `:` (in the case of the UNNEST) or immediately following the variable with the `:` (in the case of using in the `SELECT * FROM` in the query).

Because of that, I wondered if the issue is "upstream" at the `Hana ADO.NET` application query preparation and execution call level, but I ran a test and when I double checked the query string just before it is executed, it appears unchanged and the variables with `:` still look as they should, so at least as far as just before execution through `Hana ADO.NET` `HanaCommand` it looks correct - but once executing the query using `HanaDataReader` or `HanaDataAdapter` it returns the error messages referred to above. It may be a red herring to chase the problem from the `Hana ADO.NET` level but don't know what else to do.

**Update**

To further troubleshoot, I tried executing this code block below using `hdbsql.exe -n XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:30015 -u XXX -p XXX -m -I "c:\temp\test.sql" -c "#"` and it works! So, the errors I see only show up when executing the same query through the `Hana ADO.NET` interface.

```sql
DO
BEGIN

  DECLARE CODES_ARRAY NVARCHAR(10) ARRAY = ARRAY('01','02','03','04');
  DECLARE CODES_TABLE TABLE ("code" NVARCHAR(10)) = UNNEST(:CODES_ARRAY) AS ("code");

  SELECT T0."ItemCode"
  FROM OITM T0
    INNER JOIN OITW T1 ON T0."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode"
  WHERE "WhsCode" IN (SELECT "code" FROM :CODES_TABLE); -- line 10 where error occurs when using Hana ADO.NET

END;
#
```

The above fails when through `Hana ADO.NET` with the error message: `sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near ")": line 10 col 54 (at pos 325)` but works when executed through `hdbsql`.

**Update**

The C# code that executes the query is fairly straight forward, but for completeness of troubleshooting effort I am including the interesting parts of our `HanaHelper` class. This code works successfully to execute 100s of queries a day without errors or problems. This is the first time where a variable of any type has been attempted to be declared or used in a query through this code and when the errors started showing up. As far as I can tell, the issue is tied to the use of the `:` when using the variable in the query.

```c#
public class HanaHelper
{
    public HanaConnection objConn = null;

    public HanaHelper(string ConnectionString)
    {
        try
        {
            objConn = new HanaConnection(ConnectionString);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Exception thrown by HanaConnection: {0}\n{1}", e.Message, e.InnerException);
        }
    }

    public DataSet GetData(string strSQL)
    {
        using (HanaCommand objCmd = new HanaCommand(strSQL, objConn))
        {
            using (HanaDataAdapter objDA = new HanaDataAdapter(objCmd))
            {
                DataSet objDS = new DataSet();
                try
                {
                    objDA.Fill(objDS);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally 
                {
                  // do something interesting regardless of success or failure
                }
                objConn.Close();
                return objDS;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any clue here why the same query works through `hdbsql` but fails when executing through `Hana ADO.NET`?

**Update**

I figured out how to use `HanaSQLTrace` in the C# code so that I can inspect the prepared query text and viola, the source of error messages becomes apparent, all occurrences of `":VARNAME"` are replaced with `"?       "` (a `?` replaces the `:` and a space for each character in the variable name). I suppose it is trying to pre-substitute occurrences of `:` with a `?` as if there were parameters to be substituted.

How can this behavior be disabled, or worked with, or worked around so that I can use variables in a query in `Hana ADO.NET` effectively?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated based on the OP feedback.**

To refer to a variable (in order to access its value(s)) in SQLScript it's 
necessary to put a colon `:` in front of the variable name.

The main issue, however, turns out to be the declaration of the `CODES_TABLE` table variable.
With HANA 2 SPS 4 the error message is

```
`SAP DBTech JDBC: [264]: invalid datatype: unknown type SYSTEM.TABLE: line 5 col 23`
```

This points to the declaration of the TABLE typed variable `CODES_TABLE` which lacks the definition of what columns should be in the table.

Adding this fixes the issue.

With these changes, your code should work:

```
DO
BEGIN

  DECLARE CODES_ARRAY NVARCHAR(100) ARRAY = ARRAY('01','02','03','04');
  DECLARE CODES_TABLE TABLE ("code" NVARCHAR(100)) = UNNEST(:CODES_ARRAY) AS ("code"); 
  --                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  --                                     |
  ---------------------------------------+

  SELECT 
        T0."ItemCode"
  FROM 
               OITM T0
    INNER JOIN OITW T1 
      ON T0."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode"
  WHERE 
        "WhsCode" IN (SELECT "code" FROM :CODES_TABLE);
  --                                     ^
  --                                     |
  ---------------------------------------+
END;
```

An alternative option to declare and assign the table variable is to not use the `DECLARE` command.

```
DO
BEGIN

  DECLARE CODES_ARRAY NVARCHAR(100) ARRAY = ARRAY('01','02','03','04');

  CODES_TABLE = UNNEST(:CODES_ARRAY) AS ("code"); 

  SELECT 
        T0."ItemCode"
  FROM 
               OITM T0
    INNER JOIN OITW T1 
      ON T0."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode"
  WHERE 
        "WhsCode" IN (SELECT "code" FROM :CODES_TABLE);

END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input however if you notice the error message I included with each block, the one that shows up with the block that you reference here is an error on line 5 when using `:CODES_ARRAY` in the `UNNEST` function. When putting the `:` in `CODES_TABLE` on line 9 like you have it, I get the same error as the first code block I  included which is a syntax error immediately following the `:CODES_TABLE`.

Comment: I added some comments in the code blocks in my post to show the line where the error occurs

Comment: And I just added the fix for that to the answer.

Comment: I tried it but that doesn't make the error go away and I wouldn't expect it to for 3 reasons: 1) the syntax error message has a line # and a column # in it and the position of the error is inside the parenthesis of the `UNNEST` function, not in the `TABLE` definition and 2) looking at the documentation for declaring a `TABLE` variable is an example without the column definition and using UNNEST. (google `Hana Table Variable Type Definition`) and 3) if first declaring the table on one line, then set its value on another line, the error moves to the line where setting its value with the `UNNEST`

Comment: I added more to the post to include the example of a more fully defined table but also splitting the table declaration from the setting of the value and you can see that the error moves to the line where the `UNNEST` is and the use of the variable with the `:` in it.

Comment: See my recent update to the post. The code block works when executing through `hdbsql.exe` but fails with the errors I've been referring to when executing through the `Hana ADO.NET` interface used in a C# app. Any ideas?

Comment: The code works also via JDBC. This makes me assume that there is a problem with how your code and the ADO.NET driver communicate the command to HANA. Maybe you want to show your C# code to dig into this. You may also trace your application/ADO.NET calls to understand what your application is sending.  I updated the answer to include the option to use a table variable without declaring it first. THIS is what I assume you've found in the documentation - your initial option to mix `DECLARE` and then not declare the table structure just does not work at all (never did).

Comment: BTW: I swapped the `/` comment indicators to `-` as the minus sign is the standard for HANA and the forward-slash needs to be removed to make the statement work.

Comment: Thanks - I will try your updated block without the `DECLARE` a little later tonight or tomorrow. As far as the `ADO.NET` code goes, it is a fairly straight forward implementation using `HanaCommand` class to build the command connection string and `HanaDataAdapter` and `DataSet` to execute the query and fill with results - the code has been untouched for over a year and it executes 100s of Hana queries a day for a few dozen of our customers all without any problems. This is the first time however I've tried declaring and using a variable of any type in a query through this tool.

Comment: I added the C# code to a block as an update to the post.

Comment: With your changes to the code, you introduced new errors. Not sure why you seem to insist on declaring the table variable before the assignment with the `UNNEST` command - if you specify the column name with the `UNNEST` there's no need to pre-define the table variable. So ` ct = UNNEST(:ca) as (code);` works w/o issue for me. Also, the missing `:` before `ct` in the final sub-select is the first error that I get when running the command in SQL studio.

Comment: In addition, you might be on the right track with the suspicion of the `:` in the statement text. With other databases, the colon is used to indicate named host variables. This might be a problem of the `Fill`-method, which seems to be meant for SELECT commands (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill?view=netcore-3.1). But what you have here is an *anonymous SQLScript block*. That's closer to a *stored procedure* so that's the command type I would be trying to use for this.

Comment: I also tried testing with the [HanaDataReader.ExecuteReader()](https://help.sap.com/viewer/1efad1691c1f496b8b580064a6536c2d/Cloud/en-US/469dca876d611014893de752018282ee.html) method to see if, like you said, the problem was specific to the [HanaDataAdapter.Fill()](https://help.sap.com/viewer/1efad1691c1f496b8b580064a6536c2d/Cloud/en-US/469dbc9b6d6110148244a546f155c5fa.html), but both have the same response. I can''t find where it says that anonymous SQLScript blocks aren't usable. The use of anonymous SQLScript blocks is a new attempt along with the variables. Searching for an another option..

Comment: Also, FWIW, if I keep the anonymous SQLScript block structure (the `DO BEGIN ... END`) wrapper around the query code but just don't try to use the variable, it works to get the data just as if I didn't wrap the query in the block. Not sure if that tells you anything significant or not about the use of the anonymous SQLScript block and the methods referred to. It would be helpful if the source code of those class methods were available somewhere to inspect and trace what is happening inside the SAP ADO.NET code and if it is doing some sort of string replacement on `:` occurrences.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to use `HanaSQLTrace` in the C# code so that I can inspect the prepared query text and viola, the problem becomes apparent, all occurrences of `:VARNAME` are replaced with `?           `  (a `?` replaces the `:` and space for each character in the variable name).  I suppose it is trying to pre-substitute occurrences of `:` with a `?` as if there were parameters to be substituted. Now, how to disable or work with or work around this behavior? At least the issue is becoming more clear although not yet resolved.

Comment: As I don't work with .NET and don't have access to the source code of the driver (not an SAP employee) there is little I can add to that. As assumed, the .NET driver does some "magic" by replacing `:` in the statement text. Maybe this behavior can be configured or is only present with certain command types. If all other tries fail, you may have to open a support case with SAP for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215128/discussion-between-streamline-and-lars-br).