# HANA Bind JS Array as Parameter Value to WHERE IN(...) Clause

Tags: hana

I'm using the `@sap/hana-client` npm module in a NodeJS project to connect to a HANA database and run queries.
I have a list of IDs that I want to include in a `WHERE ID IN(...)` SQL clause via parameterized queries, but cannot seem to figure out the syntax to do it.

Here's what I imagine it would look like (but this does not work, fails at the parameter binding stage)

```js
const ids = [1,2,3,4];
const params = [ids];
const sql = "SELECT * FROM T WHERE ID IN (?)";

// this fails with => code: -20007, message: 'Can not bind parameter(0).', sqlState: 'HY000'
conn.query(sql, params, (err, result) => {
  // process query results or errors
});
```

I know that in Postgres I can do this by using the `UNNEST(...)` [1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) array function, but the same does not seem to work in HANA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a well-known difficulty with HANA.
ARRAY-like types are not natively supported in the client software.

Your (special) case of this, namely turning an array into a list of parameters for an `IN` clause requires some additional efforts.

See e.g. [Errors with declared array/table variable values in SAP HanaDB SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091343/errors-with-declared-array-table-variable-values-in-sap-hanadb-sql)

The bottom line is that Postgres handles this special case specifically by replacing the single `IN`-clause parameter `?` with a whole list of delimited values.

HANA does (sadly) not do something like that.

Instead, if you have to know in advance how many elements (at max) the IN-list will have so that you can prepare a statement with a parameter `?` for each of those elements.

Alternatively, you can use SQLScript and the `UNNEST` construct that I've shown in the linked question, or you can create a temporary table, fill it with the IN-list elements and use it in the `IN`-clause (or join it).

Either way, it's rather cumbersome to manually do this, and I'd probably look for a framework that does that sort of stuff.